# I want to add new line after every 4 spaces

Tags: perl

i am generating 20 numbers and then i am shuffling it

```
perl -e 'foreach(1..20){print  ",$_ "} '  
    | perl -MList::Util=shuffle -F',' -lane 'print shuffle @F'
```

and the output is:-

```
19 15 11 9 8 13 18 4 2 7 5 20 10 14 3 16 1 17 6 12
```

Now i want the output something like this:-

```
19 15 11 9

8 13 18 4

2 7 5 20

...
```

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing that in several steps on the command line is ... strange. You can just do it in one program.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use List::Util 'shuffle';

my $count = 1;
foreach my $i ( shuffle 1 .. 20) {
    print "$i ";
    print "\n\n" unless $count++ % 4;
}
```

This shuffles the list of 1 to 20 directly and then prints each item, but prints two linebreaks after every four. The `%` is the modulo operator that returns the left-over from a division by 4. So whenever the `$count` is divisible by 4, it returns 0, and the `print` kicks in. On the command line it would be like this:

```
$ perl -MList::Util=shuffle -e '$c=0; for (shuffle 1..20) { print"$_ "; print "\n\n" unless $c++%4}'
```

Here's the output:

```
11 20 8 17 

10 18 19 6 

1 14 7 5 

13 16 4 3 

9 2 15 12
```

Comment: I am using this query to generate some number and then printing only 10 numbers per line:- perl -e 'foreach (1000..1100){ $temp = int rand(999);push @rand, $temp;}while (@arr = splice(@rand, 0, 10)) {print "@arr\n"};'                now i want to make sure that all 3 digits numbers should be appended by 0 from the beginning like- 341 becomes 0341

Comment: i am using this:-perl -e 'foreach (1000..1100){ $temp = int rand(9999);push @rand, $temp;}foreach(@rand){printf "%04d ",splice(@rand,0,10)}'
but the prob is only 1 line is printing not all lines

Comment: @SonalAsija that's a new question. It doesn't really have anything to do with this answer. You want to look at `sprintf` though.

Answer (score 3):

You could also use a `splice` call to chop the result of the `shuffle` list up as you want and print it that way if you didn't want to code an explicit counter. Something like this:

```
perl -MList::Util=shuffle -e '@list=shuffle(1..20); while (@ret_line = splice(@list, 0, 4)) {print "@ret_line\n\n"}'
```

Comment: I'd make that second part a `print "@line\n\n" while @line = splice(@list, 0, 4)` to get it way shorter.

Answer (score 0):

I'd put the numbers into an array and use `splice` to remove them in blocks of four:

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all'

use List::Util 'shuffle';

my @nums = shuffle 1 .. 20;
print join(" ", splice @nums, 0, 4), "\n\n" while @nums;
```